# How to include timing for host functions in NVIDIA's visual profiler?

Tags: cuda

I have a program in which I try to overlap a host functions with a GPU kernel. To check to what extend the host function overlaps with the GPU kernel, I am using NVIDIA's visual profiler. However, the profiler doesn't show any timing results for my host function. Instead it only shows the CUDA kernel's CPU times.

Is there any way to integrate timing results of host functions into the timeline of the visual profiler?

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible.  Take a look at the NVIDIA tools extension API, which is documented in the [profiler manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvtx).

You may want to [mark a range](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvtx-range-start-stop) around the section of host code that you want to check for overlap.